# DRF additional action without suffix

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am trying to use Django Rest Framework to perform an additional action from a viewset. In the urls I have:

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'mymodels', MyModelViewSet, basename='mymodel')

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And in `views.py`:

```
class MyModelViewSet(ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
  serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

So I can send `GET /mymodel/` request. I would like to be able to send `PATCH /mymodel/`, but I don't know how to configure the action. Currently I have:

```
class MyModelViewSet(ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
  serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
  allowed_http_methods = ['get', 'patch']

  @action(methods=['patch'], detail=False, url_path='', suffix='')
  def some_action(self, request: Request) -> Response:
    # do some stuff
    return Response()
```

However, I have `405 method not allowed` response. I can send data with `PATCH /mymodel/some-action/`, but I need to get rid of the last part of the url path.

Comment: Not really. I know I can perform DELETE/PATCH etc. methods on "detail" actions, but I want to do it on non-detail one and not add the action name at the end of the url.

Comment: so in same api you want to have two path methods, first one like `PATCH api/my_api/` second one is `PARCH api/my_api/id/`. Right? Or you want to have only first one?

Comment: Only the first one.

Comment: check out my response on question from first comment link

Comment: try to replace `delete` to `patch` in decorator and func name

Comment: Oh, sorry, I only noticed the accepted response. Changing the name to "patch" did the job. Thank you for help :)